# How to control an SWFObject in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, swfobject

I'm loading an SWFObject within an HTML file.

With the next line I create an player within this object.

```
var s1 = SWFObject( 'http://www.dumpert.nl/mediabase/player4.swf',
                    'mediaplayer', '480', '388', '7');
```

How can I control this player, like play/pause or fullscreen the player with a seperate function? So I can control it from JAVA?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, read docs
http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/api

**SWFObject JavaScript API documentation**

SWFObject 2 contains an API that allows JavaScript developers to reuse SWFObject's internal functions and aims to deliver a complete tool set for publishing SWF's and retrieving Flash player related information.

---

but it also depends on what API provides the final SWF (Flash) app, if it cannot be controlled from outside, you cannot do anything via Javascript

Answer (score 3):

SWFObject is only a means to embedding a Flash object in an HTML page.  If you want the ability to control the functionality of a Flash based video player, You need to communicate with it using [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html).

You will need to ensure that functionality is written into the video player to catch calls from the JavaScript and act on them.  Here's a really simple example:

AS3:

```
//assume an FLVPlayback component called myPlayer
function stopVideoCallback():void
{
    myPlayer.stop();
}
ExternalInterface.addCallback("stopVideo", stopVideoCallback);
```

JS:

```
swfobject.getObjectById('mediaplayer').stopVideo();
```